# Do the Greenbone scan reports actually differ from a typical OpenVAS scan report?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, openvas

My company is planning to use a Greenbone appliance in the near future and wants to analyze the results with another tool. I have access to OpenVAS with GSA so I am able to test the analysis now with existing scans. But I'm not sure if I can continue to use my tool for analysis as soon I will only have access to the scans from my Greenbone appliance.

This leads to the question: Do the Greenbone reports actually differ from a typical OpenVAS scan report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got an answer to this question from a salesperson working at Greenbone. The OpenVAS-reports and the Greenbone-reports have indeed the same structure. So if you are using a parser which works on OpenVAS-reports, it will also work on the reports generated by the Greenbone appliance. The only differences are - as the salesperson put it - in quality. But this is something you should evaluate yourself, as I am in no position to justify this claim.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful, but I've been using OMP to get XML reports remotely, and the reports differ from the Greenbone console's. Not sure why this is the case, it happens even after I have disabled the filters on greenbone.

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Stack Exchange! This seems more a comment than an answer (as the question is about OpenVAS and Greenbone, rather than OMP and Greenbone). Please do not post comments as answers. Once you have 50 points, you will be able to post comments. This threshold is in place to prevent spam and off-topic chatter.